# Laravel5 Eloquent WhereNotIn not doing what I expect

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to convert in Eloquent the following SQL query :

```sql
SELECT id, title FROM chapters
JOIN chapters_has_parents
WHERE chapters.id = chapters_has_parents.parents_id
AND chapters.id
NOT IN ( SELECT children_id FROM chapters_has_parents)
```

which returns id 1 and title "introduction", as needed.

I tried lots of options, but couldn't find a correct query.
Here's my code :

```php
$startingChapter = Chapter::join('chapters_has_parents','chapters.id', '=', 'chapters_has_parents.parents_id')
->whereNotIn('chapters_has_parents.children_id', ['*'])
->get(['chapters.id', 'chapters.title']);
```

The whereNotIn doesn't work at all, whatever I try (I know the '*' isn't right but I don't get what I should put in the array.) If I remove it, I get exactly the same result.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner callback, but you’ll have to do a second query.

> whereIn(“id”, function($q) { return $query->select(“children_id”)->from(“chapter_has_parents”)->get(); })

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Querying Relationship Absence

When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the absence of a relationship. For example, imagine you want to retrieve all blog posts that don't have any comments. To do so, you may pass the name of the relationship to the doesntHave and orDoesntHave methods:

```php
$posts = App\Post::doesntHave('comments')->get();
```

If you need even more power, you may use the whereDoesntHave and orWhereDoesntHave methods to put "where" conditions on your doesntHave queries. These methods allows you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment:

```php
$posts = Post::whereDoesntHave('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
    })->get();
```